# Prevent one shape from being mouse dragged through another THREE.js

Tags: three.js, collision-detection

I'm trying to prevent one object from going through another when I'm dragging it with the mouse. Collision detection is working, I just need to prevent the shape from being dragged through the other shape.

`setForCollision: function(symbol){`

```
let cube = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.centerCube[1]);//shape is fixed in place
let cube1      = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(symbol);//dragging with mouse

if(cube1.isIntersectionBox(cube)){
    console.log(shapes touched);
    //I tried repositioning. It repositions it but doesn't really stop me from dragging it. Any suggestions?
    symbol.position.set(0,0,0);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the below is was working. I just needed to adjust the coordinates a little and it's working just fine.

`object.position.set(-7,-10,1);`